# Cannot Use Strings of Magic Constants in Function Name in PHP

Tags: php, function, syntax, constants, syntax-error

I've recently noticed that `__METHOD__` and `__CLASS__` do not return the correct name when the class is extended. And when I was writing a method for the alternative and tried to use the name `__METHOD__`, I got the following error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_METHOD_C, expecting T_STRING

```
$myclass = new myclass();
echo $myclass->__METHOD__() . '<br />';

class myclass
{
    function __METHOD__() {
        return get_class($this) . '::' . __FUNCTION__;
        // return __METHOD__;
    }
}
```

It seems PHP does not allow magic constants in a function/method name. I could not find the official documentation about this limitation. Where can I find it?

Thanks for your information.

Comment: You understand what the word "constant" means, don't you? It means you can't assign to it. What makes these constants "magic" is that their value changes depending on where they're used. But this is done by the system, you can't modify them yourself.

Comment: @Barmar `You understand what the word "constant" means, don't you?` - I believe I do. `It means you can't assign to it.` - I'm not sure if I understand this since a string of a user-defined constant can be assigned. I'd rather like to know the meaning of "language construct" as janenz00 mentioned. Is a constant a language construct?

Comment: What do you mean by "a string of a user-defined constant can be assigned"? When you do `define(A, 3);` you can't then do `A=3`. Language constructs are all the built-in syntax of the language, such as keywords like `function` and `foreach`. You can't use `__METHOD__` as a function name for much the same reason you can't use `foreach` as a function name.

Comment: @Barmar `"Cannot Use Strings of Magic Constants in Function Name in PHP - Stack Overflow"` - This is possible: `define('NAME','');
NAME();
function NAME() {}`   `"Language constructs are all the built-in syntax of the language, such as keywords like function and foreach."` - I'm still not getting whether a constant is a language construct or not.

Comment: Constants in general are not language constructs. __Magic__ constants are. They're special cases.

Comment: Oh thanks for clarifying it. So is there an official documentation explaining about this?

Comment: Not that I can find. It's just the way it is. Why does it matter?

Comment: `"Why does it matter?"` - Are you comfortable when you face with irregular behavior of the program and cannot find the official explanation for it? When I ask a question online and I often get responses like "have you read the manual?" And this time, I tried to find where it is documented and could not find any. I don't want to waste my time. That's all.

Comment: This isn't what StackOverflow is for. It's for solving programming problems, not discussing the theory behind programming language design, or omissions in the documentation.

Comment: I agree. I don't intend to discuss a thing but try to find the official explanation. Could you put an answer that states "there is no official explanation for this behavior"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently, magic constants are special -- they have more restrictions than user-defined constants.  They're more like language keywords than constants.

It doesn't seem to say it in the documentation, but it's empirically true.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

***`__METHOD__`*** is called a magic constant, which means it can be just printed, not modified by the user. You cannot use it as function name either. It is not a limitation. It is the way, the magic constants are meant to use, mainly for debugging.

The php.net page - [Magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Also check [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php). The language constructs cannot be used as variable functions names.

Comment: `You cannot use it as function name either.` - I'm looking for the official information about this. `It is not a limitation.` - I'm having hard time understanding it.

Comment: So is a magic constant a language construct? According to Wikipedia about language constructs, a language construct means `a syntactically allowable part of a program that may be formed from one or more lexical tokens in accordance with the rules of a programming language.` I don't quite get what this means.